# Strange display in Chrome. It shows empty box above documents. IE and Firefox are fine

Tags: html

Strange display in Chrome. It shows empty box above documents. IE and Firefox are fine

```
<tr>
    <td align='left' valign='middle'>
    <TABLE BORDER=5 ALIGN=CENTER CELLSPACING=5 CELLPADDING=5 width="600">
    <tr>
    <CAPTION ALIGN=CENTER>
    <B>Pay Period 20 (3/20/2011 - 4/2/2011)     Timesheet Deadline</B>
    <br><font color="red"><B>Wednesday 4/6/2011 12:00 PM Noon </B></font> 
    </B>
    </B></font> 
    <br><br><B><font color="blue" size="1">APPROVERS PLEASE NOTE:  
    IF YOUR EMPLOYEES DO NOT SUBMIT THEIR TIME SHEETS, YOU NEED TO ENTER THEIR 
    NORMAL STANDARD HOURS AND APPROVE THEIR TIME SHEETS</font></B>
    </tr>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align='left' valign='middle'>
    <TR>
    <TH COLSPAN="3"><font size=2><B>Documents</B></font></TH>
    </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <BR>
    </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Please provide a complete code example, as it stands your question is impossible to address.

Comment: Or a link to an example.

Comment: Here is a link to the html file. Sorry I was having a hard time posting the code on here


http://www.4shared.com/document/Ca3awPlI/gdfg.html

Comment: This is happening because your HTML is not valid.  You open a `<table>` tag, and then you close it in the wrong spot.  You have `</tr>` and `</td>` tags placed in wrong spots.  If you clean up your HTML and make sure everything is closed properly, it should fix your display errors.

Comment: But then why would it show without the box in firefox?

Comment: @user1345246: Some browsers are more lenient of bad HTML code.